# ASP.NET - why is the default resx file being used in the code-behind when the localized one is being used by the markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, resx

I am creating an ASP.NET web application in C#, and have to localize the application into English and French. I have created two resources files: App_GlobalResources\Resources.resx and App_GlobalResources\Resources.fr.resx containing the english and french content.

When I run the application with my browser set to French (fr_FR), the french content is correctly displayed in the markup.

Within the code-behind, when I access values from the resources, it returns the default english values only. e.g.

> this.CompanyName.Text = string.Format(App_GlobalResources.Resources.CompanyLocationsFormat, companyName);

Debugging the app shows that the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture are both correctly set to fr_FR.

Can anyone explain how I can get the code-behind to use the culturally-appropriate resource file?

Many thanks

(C#, ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, Visual Studio 2008, IE 8.0.7600)

Comment: I just ran into this problem - have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that this specific resource (CompanyLocationsFormat) exists in the french resources file? If a resource is missing, it will fall back to the default one.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes, I've checked that this resource is in the french resources file. The problem is not confined to this single resource item - it is occuring for any resource value I try to access from within the C# code. 

In the bin directory, there is a /fr directory containing a .resources.dll file.

I have noticed that the Resources.fr.Designer.cs file is empty - is this normal?

Comment: @Jon - That could be the issue; I'm not certainly how you're accessing the resources in the view, but that may use a different method than the strongly-typed wrapper that the designer creates around the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your `<system.web>` section in web.config?

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

Comment: Thanks Antony, I didn't have that in (though it was in the <%@Page %> directives on each page. I added it to the web.config, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: have you got both resx files set to the same namespace?

Comment: There doesn't look to be a namespace in the .resx files (apart from the www.w3.org namespace which is the same in both). Only the default resource has a .Designer.cs file - the .fr.resx has no C# code file.

Comment: in the properties of the resx (View | Properties) you can set the namespace.